# [Wix 3.9]How to create a single exe(bootstrapper) localized for multiple languages

Tags: wix, wix3.9

I created a wix bootstrapper application and it contains two msi packages. I want to localize my boostrapper application. My aim was to localize my bootstrapper app and it should lauch the app which is respect to the system language. means that, it should a single exe for all languages. I want to support the following languages,

1. US English
2. BZL Port
3. Intl. Spanish
4. FR
5. GR
6. Russian
7. Simplified Chinese
8. JP,
9. KR,
10. Thai
11. Arabic,
12. Traditional Chinese

My first level study, I understood that need payload files for applying localization in bootstrapper for automatically applying localization for UI translated strings. I added 3 payload files for 3 languages like english,frnch & russian. I got an exe after its build completion. Here I tried to manually selected the **LocalizationFile** file in **bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication** tag. So I got one .exe it should work only in that language. if I need to another exe for other language , need to change the **LocalizationFile** value and build it again. I want one exe which is invoked according to the system language.

Here I have following questions,

- When I used the payload file , how can I launch the setup according
  to the system language, that is if the system language is Fr, then
  run the setup file, the setup UI strings should be translated to
  french? is it possible? if so, how?
- How can I translated the **Bundle** Name in bootstrapper with respect to the system language?
- How can I translated the **DisplayName** Name in msi package with respect to the system language?
- here my msi packages also contains few strings, Is it need to add
  translated strings for each language.. I added translated strings for
  each language. After its build, sees different .msi file for each
  language. Then I manually selected the SourceFile of msi package of
  each language in boostrapper chain. it was too difficult. Have any
  other option for dynamically select the system language of msi
  package, if so, how?

Please guide me.

Regards,

George

Comment: Hi Geroge, If you got the solution for your question please share here . Thank you in advance.

Comment: I posted answer below, please look on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the payload file,we can localize the bundle project.

see the code snippet,

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
  <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
   LicenseFile=""
   LocalizationFile="Theme.wxl"
   ThemeFile="theme.xml"
   LogoFile="Images\xxx.png"
   SuppressRepair="yes"
   SuppressOptionsUI="yes"/>

  <Payload Id="thm-fr-FR" Compressed="yes" Name="1036\thm.wxl" SourceFile="theme\1036\RtfTheme.wxl" />
  <Payload Id="lic-fr-FR" Compressed="yes" Name="1036\license.rtf" SourceFile="theme\1036\EULA.rtf" />

 <Payload Id="thm-ja-JP" Compressed="yes" Name="1041\thm.wxl" SourceFile="theme\1041\RtfTheme.wxl" />
  <Payload Id="lic-ja-JP" Compressed="yes" Name="1041\license.rtf" SourceFile="theme\1041\EULA.rtf" />

  <Payload Id="thm-es-ES" Compressed="yes" Name="3082\thm.wxl" SourceFile="theme\3082\RtfTheme.wxl" />
  <Payload Id="lic-es-ES" Compressed="yes" Name="3082\license.rtf" SourceFile="theme\3082\EULA.rtf" />

</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

The name attribute of payload is important.Naming should be LCID as that of bundle recognizing LCID code.Place the localization file in the "theme\1036\RtfTheme.wxl" directory.
After doing this,change the system language from control panel and see the difference.

Thank you,

George

Comment: Is this still relevant with WiX v4? I am told by the compiler that `lic-fr-FR` is not a legal identifier and that the `licenseFile` attribute can't be empty.